# How to loop over ahk gui edit elements?

Tags: autohotkey

I need 44 edit field obviously created via loops, I can't figure out how to get the values out of the edit boxes. I want to loop over each value.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv
#include config.ahk
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

i := 20
Loop 10 {
    Gui Add, Edit, x%i% y100 w30 h20, 0
    i := i+70
}

Gui Add, Button, x275 y450 w80 h23 default, Start


Gui Show, w650 h531, Window
Return

GuiEscape:
GuiClose:
    ExitApp
```

I could store the value of one edit element in global variable and use it when I had only one box. I can't store the value in variable if I use loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to give each Edit a unique name and you can do this dynamically with a loop as you'd like. Something like this will work:

```
Gui Add, Edit, x%i% y100 w30 h20 vEditName%A_Index% , 0
```

Each Edit will then store its value in `EditName1` through `EditName44`. From there you can loop through those and store in an array or whatever you want to do.

---

*Miscellaneous, irrelevant information:*

Ah yes, this was a fun challenge for me too. For a company I used to work for, I created a GUI to manipulate the revision block on their Inventor drawings. There were four rows of repeated controls, so I wanted to **create** and **place** these dynamically - similar to what you want to do. If you'd like, I can post the code for the GUI-portion.
[image: Example GUI]
**Edit:** *Added code for above GUI*
I removed all functionality, but the code below will build the pictured GUI.

```
nRevW := 25 , nDescW := 400 , nDateW := 75 , nByW := 60
aPE := [] , nCt := 0
Gui , New , ToolWindow , Rev. Block Info. Import/Export Update
Gui , Margin , 3
Gui , Add , Text , xm+35 section w%nRevW% center , REV.
Gui , Add , Text , ys w%nDescW% center , REVISION DESCRIPTION
Gui , Add , Text , ys w%nDateW% center , DATE
Gui , Add , Text , ys w%nByW% center , CHK'D.
Loop , 4
{
    nMasterIndex := A_Index
    Loop , 4
        nVarNo%A_Index% := 4 * (nMasterIndex - 1) + A_Index
    Gui , Add , Text , xm section , Line %nMasterIndex%:
    Gui , Add , Edit , xm+35 ys w%nRevW% Center vvEdit%nVarNo1%
    If A_Index = 1
        Gui , Add , ComboBox , ys w%nDescW% vvEdit%nVarNo2% , PRELIMINARY|ISSUED FOR CHECKING & PRICING|ISSUED FOR CONSTRUCTION
    Else
        Gui , Add , Edit , ys w%nDescW% vvEdit%nVarNo2%
    Gui , Add , Edit , ys w%nDateW% Center vvEdit%nVarNo3%
    Gui , Add , Edit , ys w%nByW% Center vvEdit%nVarNo4%
    Gui , Add , Button , ys-1 w15 -TabStop vvImport%nMasterIndex% ggIELine , I
    Gui , Add , Button , x+0 ys-1 w15 -TabStop vvExport%nMasterIndex% ggIELine , E
}
Gui , Font , S7
Gui , Add , Text , xm section , Usage notes:`nMiddle-click date field to put current date.`nMiddle-click "Line [No.]:" text to clear line.
Gui , Font , S14
Gui , Add , Button , x+115 ys w75 -TabStop ggIE , Import
Gui , Add , Button , x+1 ys w75 -TabStop ggIE , Export
Gui , Add , Button , x+1 ys w140 -TabStop ggUpdate Default , Update
Gui , Add , Button , x+2 ys w30 -TabStop ggShiftUp , ▲
Gui , Show
Return

gIELine:
gIE:
gShiftUp:
gUpdate:
Return
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ofc I like to see your code. I'm intrested in everything I can learn from. I'm using other languagews most of the time and didn't though I can name the variablaes dynamically

Comment: @BrainBox Sure thing, I added the code. I did end up re-writing it in vb.net so I could build it directly into Inventor as a button in the ribbon, but this was definitely a fun project for me. I hope it helps!